# In Angular how to add subscript to matTooltip?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have to add subscript to some characters in the matTooltip. How can I do that? Like CO2, and the "2" is subscript.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert [`unicode characters`](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html) please find below working example!

```
<button
  mat-raised-button
  matTooltip="CO&#8322;"
  aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"
>
  Action
</button>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/l7rlc4?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html)

Comment: Yes, I saw that but can I do multiple characters in subscript? For example the whole "CO2" word?

Comment: @kajahun123 like this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/l7rlc4-fqjywq?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html)

Comment: But the C and O are still not in subscript.

Comment: @kajahun123 please go through the list, this is the solution to the question though!